# Calling class members from function Definition

Tags: python

Is there a way in Python to call class object from function definition ?

Let say I have class

```
class myClass():
          def __init__(self, member1 = 0)
          self.member1 = member1
```

and function definition

```
def myFunction(x):
    var1 = ............
```

I would like to assign `member1` to `var1` in function definition.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it:

```
class myClass():
    def __init__(self, member1 = 5):
        self.member1 = member1

def myFunction(x):
    var1 = myClass().member1
    print x, var1


myFunction(2)
```

prints 2 5

myClass class is global to the module so it can be seen inside the function.

Comment: Well, you did not say you wanted to assign to myClass().member1 in your specification. Why to do that?. I would understand you want to assign a value to var1, or to member1 inside the class, or at class instantiation, even as myClass(1).member1...

Answer (score 3):

Do you understand what classes are for?

You would like to assign `member1` **of which instance of the class** to `var1`?

Is `x` supposed to be an instance of `myClass` that you're passing to `myFunction`? Then it's simple: `var1 = x.member1`.

Comment: Unfortunately `x` is not class. That would certainly make things a lot nicer.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need `member1` to be a static class variable. See [Static class variables in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python).